# Rails5 how to write a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I write a route in Rails 5 so that when a user visits

```
http:www.mysite.com/volunteer_events/add_shift
```

it fires the add_shift method inside the volunteer_events controller

I have spent hours staring at the routing page here...https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.7/routing.html ...and it's just turning into a giant wall of text.

This is what I currently have...

```
  get '/volunteer_events/add_shift', to: 'volunteer_events#add_shift'
```

But I'm getting an error

```
Couldn't find VolunteerEvent with 'id'=add_shift
```

I know this is simple...I'm just very tired and I don't remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the rest of your `route.rb` file look?

Routes are interpreted from top to bottom with routes defined higher having a higher precedence. My assumption is that you have something like this in the routes

```rb
resources :volunteer_events
get '/volunteer_events/add_shift', to: 'volunteer_events#add_shift'
```

which would translate to something like this

```rb
get '/volunteer_events/:id', to: 'volunteer_events#show'
get '/volunteer_events/add_shift', to: 'volunteer_events#add_shift'
```

Now your first route has always precedence over the second one and `add_shift` will always be interpreted as the id for the `show` route (note the `:id` in the show routes which is a parameter). Just flip the two so `/volunteer_events/add_shift` will be matched before your show route and you should be good.